# Update redux state object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

How do I update the property of an object in redux and preserve the rest of the object..

```
const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        user: { loggedIn: true, level: 'default' },
      });

    case 'UPDATE_PACKAGE': {
      // add a new value for the user.level which would be in action.level
      return { ...state, level: action.level };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

So I would expect the UPDATE_PACKAGE to change the contents of the redux store level property... but its unchanged...

Comment: What's `console.log(action.level);` showing? also how do you know the state isn't updated properly?

Comment: Do you want to show your data on first render????, I feel you want to do this is it???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems like you're setting `level` on the root state instead of the user object.

This should fix it:

```
 case "UPDATE_PACKAGE": {
    return { ...state, user: { ...state.user, level: action.level } };
  }
```